# I am trying Selenium Webdriver to find input element by class name

Tags: selenium

How to find element `input class="Test_type"`? I successfully got by `id=Test1` but failing to find element by `input class="Test_type"`

I have tried:

```
WebElement mainform = driver.findElement(By.className("mainform"));

List<WebElement> postadchildone2 = mainform.findElements(By.className("formrow"))

for(WebElement formrow: postadchildone2)
{
    WebElement formfield = formrow.findElement(By.className("formfield"));
    WebElement inputclass = formfield.findElement(By.className("Test_type"))

}
```

Also tried using CSS selector & XPath, however still it says didn't found, because of the same class name it is not finding `input class`.

Under `for` loop I tried doing

```
formrow.getText()
```

It displays all the text results but it is not taking class name? I am stuck please help

HTML:

```
<div class="mainform">
  <div class="formrow">
    <div class="formrow">
      <div class="formrow">
        <div class="formfield">
          <div id="Test1" class="city_select">
            <div class="blank1"/>
            <div class="formrow " style="margin-left:10px;">
              <div class="formrow">
                <div class="formlabel">
                   <strong>You Are</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="formfield">
                  <label>
                    <input class="Test_type required" type="radio"/>
                    YouareTest
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried making it sleep before searching for the field? Sometimes selenium goes quickly over it before it's in the interface so you can't view it.

Comment: Hi Decypher, ya I tried Sleep also, didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

as you have the following piece of code:

```
<div class="formfield">
    <label>
    <input class="Test_type required" type="radio"/>
      YouareTest
    </label>
</div>
```

We need to outline input element somehow. 
So I recommend to locate this element using CSS selector because it is the fastest way. 
So `'input'` tag has  following class attribute= `"Test_type required"` , that means that to this element 2 CSS  classes are applied:

- Test_type
- required
  When locating with CSS selector element, an element B with class attribute y will be notated as  `B.y`, an element with 2 class attributes  y and z will be notated as `B.y.z` then. 
  So in terms of our task it will look like

  ```
    input.Test_type.required
  ```

But also you can notice that you have another element - div with class attribute =`formfield` as parent element. 
So to locate child element to parent  with CSS in the structure like:

```
 <parent class="zz">
     <child 1>
        <child2> abaracadabra</child>
     </child 1>
    </parent>
```

**parent.zz child2**  => in this way

So the second part of our selector be like : 
`div.formfield` as it be parent selector in relation to input.
So solution combo =

```
WebElement inputt=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.formfield input.Test_type.required'));
```

Please try this one, and tell whether it works for you or not.

Comment: An answer that contains code with no description isn't very helpful. Can you explain a little bit about your solution?

Comment: @BryanOakley, provided detalization ;-)

Comment: Nice job, Eugene. _much_ better answer now.

Comment: @eugene,I have tried above explained way, it says: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.formfield input.Test_type.required"}

I have tried below code:
`List<WebElement> postadchildone2 = mainform.findElements(By.className("formrow"));
System.out.println("Post ad form count: "+postadchildone2.size());
                  for(WebElement formrow: postadchildone2)
 {
WebElement Individual = formrow.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.formfield input.Test_type.required"));
     
Individual.click();
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to fetch with only partial class name, try using the below code

```
WebElement inputclass = formfield.findElement(By.CssSelector("Input[class*='Test_type'"))
```

Comment: input does not have  'id' attribute, it has 'class' attribute. this selector will not work.

Comment: Typo mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried above method, on running program it says:   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"Input[class*='Test_type']"}

Comment: Did your page was completely loaded?

Comment: @Sham
Code I used:
`List<WebElement> postadchildone2 = mainform.findElements(By.className("formrow"));
System.out.println("Post ad form count: "+postadchildone2.size());
 for(WebElement formrow: postadchildone2)
{
WebElement formfield = formrow.findElement(By.className("formfield"));
     WebElement inputclass = formfield.findElement(By.cssSelector("Input[class*='Test_type']"));
}`

Comment: @Sham,Yes it was completely loaded, in my scenario there are few text fields which I fill first and few radio button's which I select, then at the bottom I try to select above field for which error is occurring, so Page load is not an issue